# Subtract concatenated dates with CASE

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

In a select statement, I would like to subtract concatenated dates to determine the OEM warranty flag.  I receive error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.
What am I missing here?

```
--OEM WARRANTY FROM MFG SERIAL AND RECV DATE
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(a.RECV_DATE, 'MM/DD/YY') -
TO_CHAR(CASE 
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'A' THEN '01'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'B' THEN '02'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'C' THEN '03'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'D' THEN '04'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'E' THEN '05'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'F' THEN '06'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'G' THEN '07'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'H' THEN '08'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'J' THEN '09'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'K' THEN '10'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'L' THEN '11'
WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'M' THEN '12'
ELSE 'FIRST CHAR OF MFG SERIAL INCORRECT' END
||'/' || SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 10, 2) ||'/'|| SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 2, 2)), 'MM/DD/YY')
> '365' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y'
END AS "OEM WARR"
```

Comment: Please do not type your question title in ALL CAPS. Just like everywhere else on the internet, typing in ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING. There is no need to shout here; we're all very good readers. Shouting will not get you answers more quickly, it makes text more difficult to read, and it's rather rude and annoying. There is no reason to shout to get attention here - if someone can help you, they will without the CAPS text.

Comment: @mathguy: Yep. At the same time I did. You missed removing the tag info. My comment still stands; the poster should be made aware that it's inappropriate conduct here.

Comment: I always write my scripts in all caps and find it easier to read, a matter of opinion.  I did not intend to shout or be rude in any way and figured people reading this forum would "get it", but apparently not.  BTW, the only post in caps is my code.  When you use the tab function in intellisense when writing the code it defaults to all caps.  STOP (shouting) trolling.

Comment: Your entire title was in CAPS (which I edited to remove). I could give a rat's behind how you choose to write your scripts; I simply asked that you not type your question **title** in ALL CAPS. Stop being snarky and (learn to) accept constructive advice. Trying to be helpful and explain site etiquette is not *trolling*.

Comment: I'll point you to the [help], which explains both that this site is moderated by its users, and that acceptable behavior here does not include personal insults or name calling. Please be polite. If you're offended by the standards and conduct expectations here, feel free to go ask your questions elsewhere.

Comment: mountain out of an ant hill...(no upper case so don't get offended)

Comment: It wasn't until you made it one. You're the one who's been carrying on, getting rude and calling names. The proper response from the beginning was *Thanks for pointing that out (and fixing it for me). I'll keep that in mind in the future.*. Try that next time.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two strings (with `TO_CHAR()`), then you subtract one from the other, and then you compare to the string '365'? How do you suppose one STRING is subtracted from another?

You probably meant to have those as `TO_DATE()` - and then compare the difference to the number `365`, not the string `'365'`.

Answer (score 0):

The most glaring thing to me is trying to subtract character strings when you're actually wanting to subtract dates.  Maybe something like this:

```
CASE WHEN a.RECV_DATE -
TO_DATE(
  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'A' THEN '01'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'B' THEN '02'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'C' THEN '03'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'D' THEN '04'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'E' THEN '05'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'F' THEN '06'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'G' THEN '07'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'H' THEN '08'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'J' THEN '09'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'K' THEN '10'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'L' THEN '11'
       WHEN SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1) = 'M' THEN '12'
  END || '/' || SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 10, 2) ||'/'|| 
                SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 2, 2)), 'MM/DD/YY') > 365 
  THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as "OWM WARR"
```

(Untested)

As for the error message, I don't think you can do this in a pure SQL context. Is this part of a PL/SQL program?  If not, then you should probably restrict your data to valid months in the WHERE clause.

More compact:

```
CASE WHEN a.RECV_DATE -
   TO_DATE(DECODE(SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1), 
   'A','01', 'B','02', 'C','03', 'D','04', 'E','05', 'F','06'
   'G','07', 'H','08', 'J','09', 'K','10', 'L','11', 'M','12')
   || '/' || SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 10, 2) ||'/'|| 
             SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 2, 2)), 'MM/DD/YY') > 365 
THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as "OWM WARR"
```

Comment: Thank you DCookie.  I made a few syntax updates to your compact version and got it to work.  I am a SQL server guy learning Oracle so this was very helpful!  Here is what I ended up with:

Answer (score 0):

### This worked!

```
--MANUFACTURER DATE
--DECODE MFG SERIAL MONTH
TO_DATE(DECODE(SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1), 
'A','01', 'B','02', 'C','03', 'D','04', 'E','05', 'F','06',
'G','07', 'H','08', 'J','09', 'K','10', 'L','11', 'M','12')
|| '/' || SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 10, 2) ||'/'|| 
SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 2, 2), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "MFG DATE",
---------------------------------------------------------------------
--OEM WARRANTY FROM MFG SERIAL AND RECV DATE
CASE WHEN a.RECV_DATE -
TO_DATE(DECODE(SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 1, 1), 
'A','01', 'B','02', 'C','03', 'D','04', 'E','05', 'F','06',
'G','07', 'H','08', 'J','09', 'K','10', 'L','11', 'M','12')
|| '/' || SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 10, 2) ||'/'|| 
SUBSTR(a.CARD_RECV_SERIAL_NBR, 2, 2), 'MM/DD/YYYY') > 365 
THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as "OEM WARR"
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```